# foreach loop not working in php code

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach, nested

Only first row is printing. Others are not printing.

Only getting a submit button in other rows

no errors or warnings found in code.

`$v` and `$u` array is same. When `$v` is used in both `foreach` nothing is printing.

```
<?php 
  foreach ($v->result() as $row)
  {
?>
  <tr>  
    <?php echo form_open('add_exam', array('role' => 'form', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')); ?>
    <?php
      foreach ($u->list_fields() as $field)  
      {
    ?>
        <td class='hidden-1024'>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $field; ?>" name="<?php echo $field; ?>" value="<?php echo $row->$field;?>">
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
    <td class='hidden-1024'>
      <?php echo form_submit(array('name' => 'score_submit', 'id' => 'score_submit', 'value' => 'Save', 'class' => 'btn btn-embossed btn-primary m-r-20'));?>
    </td>    
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
  </tr>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: Post the array structure of `$v`

Comment: Try to `print_r($v->result());`.

Comment: you are forgetting the colon : in the php for each loop and you must close it too <?php   foreach ($v->result() as $row) :?> .... code here .... <?php endforeach; ?>  read more  about native php templating here http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Did you see the produced html?lots of form without ending. Try to learn little more html before php

Comment: @Uchiha This is that in the Controller `$data['u']=$this->select_exam_model->select_mark($table_exam);                  $data['v']=$this->select_exam_model->select_mark($table_exam);                 $this->load->view('add_exam_view_multi_mark',$data);`

Comment: print_r($v->result());

Comment: @Uchiha print_r($v->result()); prints everything

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [roll_no] => 1 [student_name] => sajeev somanathan [malayalam_score] => [malayalam_grade] => [Physics_score] => [Physics_grade] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [roll_no] => 2 [student_name] => sdfgh [malayalam_score] => [malayalam_grade] => [Physics_score] => [Physics_grade] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [roll_no] => 3 [student_name] => Abdul Jabbar [malayalam_score] => ` etc.....

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola print_r($v->result()); prints everything

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [roll_no] => 1 [student_name] => sajeev somanathan [malayalam_score] => [malayalam_grade] => [Physics_score] => [Physics_grade] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [roll_no] => 2 [student_name] => sdfgh [malayalam_score] => [malayalam_grade] => [Physics_score] => [Physics_grade] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [roll_no] => 3 [student_name] => Abdul Jabbar [malayalam_score] => ` etc.....

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
value="<?php echo $row->field;?>"
```